# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework get related data object

Tags: asp.net, relationship, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Every time I am trying to get a related object I get error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Relevant code:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Developer> MyDevs { get; set; }
}

public class Developer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Skills { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }  
    public virtual Project MyProj { get; set; }
}

//define relationship using fluent api, under AppDbContext
modelBuilder.Entity<Developer>()
.HasOne(d => d.MyProj)
.WithMany(p => p.MyDevs)
.HasForeignKey("ProjectForeignKey");
```

Add-migration and update-database give no error, but I am not able to find the myDev column in the Project table. I am not able to find the myProj column in the Developer table either, only the foreignkey column.

Running the following seed method adds one project and one developer to the db as expected.

```
public static void Seed(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
{
    AppDbContext context = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
    Project ProjA = new Project { ProjName = "handyApp", Description  = "a dummy Project" };
    context.Project.Add(projA);
    Developer FirstDev = new Developer { UserName = "John Smith", Skills = "C#", Email = "jsmith@dummymail.com", MyProj = ProjA};
    context.Developer.Add(FirstDev);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then running the following code hits the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception.

```
Developer Dev = context.Devs.Find(1);
string name = Dev.MyProj.ProjName;  //put a break point here, the dubugger tells me Dev.MyProj is null
```

Please can anyone help to identify what is wrong with my relationship definition.

Comment: *Every time I am trying to get a related object* -- So show the code where you do that.

Comment: The relationship *definition* is ok. But you need to ask EF to load (populate) the navigation property. See [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) documentation topic.

Comment: @aaron, yes and it is the correct project Id

Comment: @GertArnold added, thanks

Comment: @thanks, that solves the problem...

Answer (score 0):

As @ Ivan Stoev pointed out, Lazy loading is not yet supported by EF Core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data